# How do I consume data from a component where I am passing data using Link of react-router in class Components?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, state

I have a carousel of cards. And each card has some data which if I click on the button on the card. I want to render the details of that particular card in different components on a different page which is item-details.

How do I achieve this in class components? There is an id in the map can I send using that in the details page where I am trying to render the full details of the card.

```
                        {this.state.data.map((item, idx) => {
                            return (
                                <div key={`edth_${idx}`} className="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 item explore-item" data-groups={item.group}>
                                    <div className="card">
                                        <div className="image-over">
                                                 <img className="card-img-top" src={item.img} alt="" />
                                         </div>
                                         <div className="card-caption col-12 p-0">
                                             <div className="card-body">
                                                <a href="/item-details">
                                                    <h5 className="mb-0">{item.title}</h5>
                                                </a>
                                                
                                                <div className="card-bottom d-flex justify-content-between">
                                                    <span>{item.price}</span>
                                                    <span>{item.count}</span>
                                                </div>
                                                <Link to={{pathname: '/item-details',state: [{img:'item.img',count: 'item.count', title: 'item.title', price: 'item.price'}]}} className="btn btn-bordered-white btn-smaller mt-3"> <i className="icon-handbag mr-2" />Check it out</Link>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            );
                        })}
                    </div>
```

I have added the Link from react router instead of, but I still don't know how to consume this in the component which will be in /item-details.

Found out that instead of useLocation, I can use with router in class components so...

Imported useRouter in the item-details page and consuming like this in the render():

```
render() {
        const { location } = this.props;
                return (
                            <div className="item-info">
                                {location && location.img && <div className="item-thumb text-center">
                                    <img src={location.img}  />
                                </div>}
);
```

By doing this, I am not getting any error. But the img is not showing.

Comment: what exactly is the issue ?

Comment: @EmmanuelPonnudurai Here when i  am clicking the button which  <a
                className="btn btn-bordered-white btn-smaller mt-3"
                href="/item-details"
              > i want to pass item details like item.count item.title to /item-details page. Where i will use the  details of a particular card which i click on it. How do i achieve this?

Comment: OK. the simplest way that I see is, just pass them as queryParams. something like `href="/item-details?count={count}&title={titlle}"`. This also maens that the other page you redirect to, should be able to use those queryParams and use them. You could use react router library if you want to have rich support for these kind of operations but thats not relevant to your app as I dont know the complete make up of your app.

Comment: What is the issue? Is the route state not working? Access route state on the receiving route's component in the [location object](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/location).

Comment: React Hook "useLocation" cannot be called in a class component. That's why even though i pass something in Link i cannot consume it using useLocation

Comment: Have you tried any of the other number of ways to access the `location` object? Can you share how you are trying to access the route state? Can we see how it's rendered by a router? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @DrewReese Added.

Comment: Just checking in if you still wanted to update your question to include a complete code example to show us how the component is rendered by a router/route, and how it accesses the route props.

Answer (score 1):

React is generally used for a single paged application (i.e. you wouldn't be sending users to different URLS) unless you are using something like NEXT, React Router, etc. for handling different pages.

Instead of sending the user to another page, you would render a new component with the details sent as a prop.

But if you're asking how to send information from a component to another page, i would suggest you look into [React Router](https://reactrouter.com/), which is designed to do this.

I'm not sure if this is actually what you're asking though so please provide further details on what your project is made up of.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, the best way to handle this would be to set the URL query when the onClick() handler is run. The view would update & the details would be fetched as needed. That way if you your homepage is mysite.com you can get more details by visiting mysite.com/moreinfo.

To accomplish this, you can use react-router-dom history API:

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

function myComponent() {
  let history = useHistory();

  function handleClick() {
    history.push("/moreinfo");
  }

  return (
    <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>
      View More Info
    </button>
  );
}
```

Comment: What about the data which i am passing  how do i consume it and that too in a class component.

Comment: Instead of passing props or prop drilling, I would use something like Reacts useEffect hook to fetch the data from its source when the page is loaded. I'm really not sure where your getting your data from to be able to answer that. Could you provide a bit more details?

Comment: Sorry just realized your using Classes, so the equivalent would be componetDidMount.